# with pandas and matplotlib, how can I draw a graph when I exclude some rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this (index is the timestamp, so it is a datetime type):

```
timestamp                price        quantity   direction    aggregated
2020-09-04 00:00:00.000  381.501760     3.000         s        True
2020-09-04 00:00:00.212  381.530000     3.225         s       False
2020-09-04 00:00:00.560  381.346627   207.477         s        True
2020-09-04 00:00:00.590  381.450000     2.586         s       False
2020-09-04 00:00:00.652  381.540000     0.030         b       False
...
```

and I want to do a rolling window on the price, but ONLY on the rows where *aggregated* = True

```
df[df['aggregated'] == True]['price'].rolling("25s", min_periods=1).mean()
```

the code I use to draw is this:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(20, 10), sharex='all', gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [4, 1]}, constrained_layout=True)

p0=ax1.plot(df.index, df['price'], color='darkorange', zorder = 0)
p1=ax2.plot(df.index, df[df['aggregated'] == True]['price'].rolling("25s", min_periods=1).mean(), color='blue')
```

but I get the following error:

> x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (487452,) and (188252,)

if I remove the test on the *aggregated* column, I get this:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(20, 10), sharex='all', gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [4, 1]}, constrained_layout=True)

p0=ax1.plot(df.index, df['price'], color='darkorange', zorder = 0)
p1=ax2.plot(df.index, df['price'].rolling("25s", min_periods=1).mean(), color='blue')
```

and it works. So I guess it doesn't like that some rows are missing.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `.plot` expects two arrays of the same size, and you are passing a longer array with `df.index`.

Try

```
filtered = df[df['aggregated'] == True]['price'].rolling("25s", min_periods=1).mean()

...

p1 = ax2.plot(filtered.index, filtered.price, color='blue')
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, you filtered your `y` values, but left the sequence of `x` values referring to the original data set.  You need to re-extract the ordinal sequence form the same filtered data set.

Try creating a new data frame, say df_plot.  Then use `df_plot.index`, not the original data frame's `df.index`.

Is that enough of a hint?

Answer (score 0):

As Prune said, you want to plot to the ones that are "aggregated" against the ones that are "aggregated" (;)) and that means they have to have same size.
Try using same mask:

```
p0=ax1.plot(df.index, df['price'], color='darkorange', zorder = 0)
p1=ax2.plot(df[df['aggregated'] == True].index, df[df['aggregated'] == True]['price'].rolling("25s", min_periods=1).mean(), color='blue')
```

Comment: that wouldn't work since I need the first graph to show all values

Comment: I moved mask to second line "index" (or x's) part, that should place "aggregated" y's at their x's

Comment: yes, that will work; it's what RichieV and Prune proposed.